# MY show/hide happens to all loop results instead of one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Issue: Show/hide javascript function when clicked opens all do loop results.  I need for it to only open the one result the "Edit" is within/clicked for.

The forms textfield is hidden until "Edit" is clicked on.  The table can have more than one result so when the table does have 2+ results, the "Edit" button clicked works on all of the loop results instead of just the one it's clicked for.

html:

```
<div class="form-show"><a href="" id="form-show">Edit</a></div>

<div id="form-hide">
    <!--form and text_field-->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('a#form-show').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div#form-hide').toggle();
  });
});
```

The form is a do loop (loops through results).

How can I alter the javascript so when a user clicks "Edit", only the 1 result can be edited instead of all of the results?

**Entire form:**

```
<td class="center ">
  <div class="form-show"><%= user.field %>% <a href="" id="form-show">Edit</a></div>
      <div id="form-hide">
          <%= form_for user, remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :field, class: "form-cotrol" %>
          <%= f.button data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light " do %>
             <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: We need more please. Let's see a complete example. It seems easy enough to create one right here on the page. Then the solution will be very easy.

Comment: Looks to me like your using duplicate id, this is a no - no, switch to classes and make id unique.

Comment: @RandyCasburn hey thanks .  i added the entire form and the div classes/ids... its in ruby syntax tho

Comment: @Bibberty they are both using IDs

Comment: Bibberty's point is that they cannot be identical. In your Ruby, you have two loops, the outer one creates `<div id=form-hide>` - if there is more than one of these, the Ids are all the same and as Bibberty says - that's a no-no.

Comment: id should be unique .. and you can use `$(this).parent().next('div').toggle()` and instead of `$('a#form-show')` you can use `$('.form-show > a')`

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's why the issue is happening but how can I make it so the javascript can differentiate between the multiple loop results?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef ayyy, that worked.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: you're totally welcome @uno .. but be sure to don't duplicate ids .. when looping use classes instead .. or use unique id for each element .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't neccessarily an answer but if you are reading this and having the same issues.

Please read the comments under the OP by @ Mohamed-Yousef ... his response solved and answered the question but he didn't make a response/answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next) to find the next occurrence of the editable div:

```
$(function() {
  $('a#form-show').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.next($('div#form-hide')).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing appears when I click "Edit" with this